# C++ Use atoi() to convert a single character instead of multiple characters

Tags: c++, string, c++17

I am sending a message over the network with the following simple code:

```
SSL_write(ssl, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
```

I am then recieving the message on the server and converting the first character of the message to an int, with the following code:

```
char buf[1024] = {0};
SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
std::cout << atoi(&buf[0]);
```

This code works relatively well because if the string is something like "1foo", the server will print out "1" to the console. 
However, if the string is "12foo", the server will print out "12", instead of "1".

How can I fix this, so the server only prints out the first character of the string (as an int)?

Comment: You fix this by reading the documentation of `atoi()`, paying attention to the part that explains that it uses a C-style `'\0'`-terminated `char` buffer, and then updating your code accordingly.

Comment: `std::cout << static_cast<int>(buf[0] - '0');`

Comment: @nikniknik2016 because it is not going to do what OP wants?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Wow! Coming from a non-C++ background, I didn't realize that  `atoi()` doesn't just convert the referred to by `&buf[0]`  to a int, but instead uses the fact that `&buf[0]` is a reference to continue reading values from `buf`. I guess I need to further work on understanding the practical usages of references/pointers in C++.

Comment: @Roymunson `buf` is a `char[]` array, where `buf[0]` is a single `char`, so `&buf[0]` is a `char*` pointer.  `atoi()` simply assumes that the `char*` passed to it is null-terminated.  This is documented behavior! But the contents of your `buf` are not null-terminated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be (provided you are working with ASCII encoding):

```
int v = buf[0] - '0';
cout << v;
```

Comment: This conversion does **not** depend on ASCII. Both C and C++ require that the encodings for the characters `’0’ .. ‘9’` be contiguous and increasing. That means that `buf[0] - ‘0’` works for every character encoding.

Comment: Assuming `buf[0]` contains a `char` in the range of `'0'..'9'`, that is. The OP's code example does not guarantee that. Subtracting `'0'` from any `char` not in that range will yield undesirable results.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was not aware of that! Good to know. Would you be so kind to provide a reference to this requirement?

Comment: "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous." [lex.charset]/3. The "above list" is the decimal digit characters `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.